# How to Split array of strings into sets of arrays alphabetically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given an array of strings, how can I split these strings into different arrays alphabetically?

example:

```
let array = ['cheese', 'corn', 'apple', 'acorn', 'beet', 'banana', 'yam', 'yucca']

// return should be something like:

a = ['apple', 'acorn']
b = ['banana', 'beet']
c = ['cheese', 'corn']
y = ['yam', 'yucca']
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: SO is not your own personal code-writing service - show what you've tried if you want debugging help.

Comment: Have you solve these scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For

```
let words = ["corn", "to", "add", "adhere", "tree"]
```

Doing this

```
  const getSections = () => {
    if (words.length === 0) {
      return [];
    }
    return Object.values(
      words.reduce((acc, word) => {
        let firstLetter = word[0].toLocaleUpperCase();
        if (!acc[firstLetter]) {
          acc[firstLetter] = { title: firstLetter, data: [word] };
        } else {
          acc[firstLetter].data.push(word);
        }
        return acc;
      }, {})
    );
 }
```

Will result in a nice grouping like,

```
[{title: 'T', data: ["to", "tree"]}, ...]
```

which goes along pretty well with `SectionList` in ReactNative.

Comment: It's like you read my mind. That's exactly what I was trying to do and for exactly that reason. This is a very nice solution, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The most sensible thing would be to create a dictionary object rather than trying to assign to a bunch of individual variables. You can do that easily here with `reduce()`:

```js
let array = ['cheese', 'corn', 'apple', 'acorn', 'beet', 'banana', 'yam', 'yucca']

let dict = array.reduce((a, c) => {
    // c[0] should be the first letter of an entry
    let k = c[0].toLocaleUpperCase()

    // either push to an existing dict entry or create one
    if (a[k]) a[k].push(c)
    else a[k] = [c]

    return a
}, {})

console.log(dict)

// Get the A's
console.log(dict['A'])
```

You'll, of course, want to make sure the original array holds sensible values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This answered my question exactly. I'm curious how to accomplish this if that fruit was the value of a property in an array of objects. `[{id: 1, fruit: "apple"}, {id: 2, fruit: "banana"}]`

Comment: @ChristopherR. you'll be able to do almost the same thing, but inside the the reduce, you will need to pull out the specific property you want — something like: `k = c['fruit'][0].toUppercase` and `a[k].push(c['fruit'])`

Answer (score 3):

You can also populate a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object from your array and then get values based on keys (first character of string):

```js
let array = ['cheese', 'corn', 'apple', 'acorn', 'beet', 'banana', 'yam', 'yucca'];

let map = ((m, a) => (a.forEach(s => {
  let a = m.get(s[0]) || [];
  m.set(s[0], (a.push(s), a));
}), m))(new Map(), array);

console.log(map.get("a"));
console.log(map.get("b"));
console.log(map.get("c"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```